# Traversing Template Parameter Packs, what is the role of the specialization which takes no argument?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

I have the following piece of code:

```
template<typename... Types>
struct TupleSize;

template<typename Head, typename... Tail>
struct TupleSize<Head, Tail...>
{
    static const size_t value = sizeof(Head) + TupleSize<Tail...>::value;
};

template<> struct TupleSize<>
{
    static const size_t value = 0;
};


int main()
{
    //consuming_templates();
    //template_functions();
    //variadic();
    TupleSize<>::value;
    TupleSize<int, double, char>::value;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I do not understand what is the role of:

```
template<typename... Types>
struct TupleSize;
```

Where is actually being used because I know that TupleSize<>::value; returns 0 and the other piece of code:

```
template<typename Head, typename... Tail>
struct TupleSize<Head, Tail...>
{
    static const size_t value = sizeof(Head) + TupleSize<Tail...>::value;
};
```

is used to split the parameter pack and recursively calculate the value.

Is this just a declaration, if yes why, if not where is it being used. The only scenario I can immagine is when the recursion hits its final value i.e becomes TupleSize. But I do not understand how can a template struct type exists like this, shouldn't it be:

```
template<typename... Types>
struct TupleSize<typename... Types>;
```

Comment: "`template<typename... Types> struct TupleSize<typename... Types>;`" isn't a valid declaration in C++. C++'s syntax is simply not this. A template declaration consists of (briefly) declaring the parameters of the template followed by its name. That's it. If the template name's is then followed by a template parameter list it's not a declaration but, at most, a specialization; and the template must be declared already.

Comment: Looks potentially dangerous to me. Your template is collecting the size of the single members, but that can differ from the size of the corresponding `std::tuple`, as the latter might need to insert some padding bytes due to alignment reasons. Additionally: `sizeof(std::tuple<>)` necessarily is 1.

Comment: Observe that, if you declare **and** define the primary template as follows `template<typename...>
struct TupleSize
 { static const size_t value = 0; };`, you can delete the zero-parameters specialization and all works exactly as before: when you call `TupleSize` with one or more parameters, the specialization is selected (because is more specialized), when you call it with zero parameters, the specialization doesn't matches so the primary template is selected (but, IMHO, your version is preferable as more readable) .

Comment: @Aconcagua It depends on the objective. Perhaps the template name should be modified to ‘packed_size‘ or something; this can be used to measure memory waste of ‘std::tuple‘ or implement some sort of memory efficient tuple.

Comment: @Red.Wave That would serve only for the waste of the tuple itself, but how much value does this provide? Tuple members themselves might waste memory, too, which wouldn't be covered, so I have some doubts about... Agree, there still might be some valid use case for, and totally agree on a better name preventing possible misunderstandings. Still my comment remains valid: *if* original name reveals actual intention, *then* it likely is bound to fail...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this just a declaration, if yes why, if not where is it being used.

It's the declaration of the primary template, taking arbitrary template parameters. It has two specializations; the primary template is never used, because when specify 1 template argument or several template arguments more than 1, the 1st specialization is selected; if specify no template argument (empty) the 2nd specialization is selected.